# Does the Millennium Falcon have computer round socket terminals which are Scomp link compatible?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

It seems to be commonplace to find [scomp](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Scomp_link) computer socket terminals in space ships in the Star Wars universe — like the Razor Crest — as a way to permit access to computer system and communicate information within [astromech](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Astromech_droid) droids

Knowing that — and is it mentioned in Canon/Legends — does the Millennium Falcon have scomp terminals?

[image: Still from The Mandalorian - S01E06 - Chapter 6 - The Prisoner]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the 2012 (Legends) [*Millennium Falcon Owner's Manual*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon_Owner%27s_Workshop_Manual), the Falcon is replete with scomp interfaces. One in the cockpit and one on each engineering station.

> The cockpit console is equipped with a socket for an astromech droid's
> scomp link, which allows a droid to insert jump coordinates and — if
> necessary — control the ship. Similar scomp links are also built into
> the Falcon’s technical and engineering stations.

This is backed up in the 2018 (Canon) *[Star Wars: Millennium Falcon: A 3-D Owner's Guide](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Millennium_Falcon:_A_3-D_Owner%27s_Guide_(2018))*

> **NAV COMPUTER**
>
> The YT-1300 navigational computer
> works with the hyperdrive and
> sensors to calculate jumps through
> hyperspace. **All cockpit consoles
> are equipped with a socket for
> an astromech droid’s scomp link,** allowing the droid to insert jump
> autopilot.